# Dismissing ProgressDialogs cause warnings

Tags: android, progressdialog

I've implemented a few `ProgressDialog`s in my app like this:

```
ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
mDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
mDialog.setCancelable(false);
mDialog.show();
// ...
mDialog.dismiss();
```

But after being dismissed, the following warnings show on Logcat:

```
W/Dialog﹕ dismiss E
W/Dialog﹕ dismiss 2
W/Dialog﹕ dismissDialog E
W/Dialog﹕ sendDismissMessage E
W/Dialog﹕ sendDismissMessage X
W/Dialog﹕ dismissDialog X
W/Dialog﹕ dismiss X
```

The app doesn't crash, nothing unexpected happens, except for the warnings. I was wondering if I've done something wrong to cause the warnings and how can I fix it.

Comment: Those definitely don't look like standard Android error messages and your code looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are using a custom rom or a "not-so-popular" device for testing. The Devs that worked on that rom, have forgot those logs there. Shame on them.

There is nothing wrong with your code from what I can see.

Comment: Sounds quite plausible. This device is one of those Chinese Galaxy SIII copycats with a custom Gingerbread ROM that tries to impersonate the Ice Cream Sandwich version. I'll try to find another device to test, or even the emulator.